# Does dismissal due to absence relate to academic or non-academic suspension/dismissal?

Tags: graduate-admissions, academic-history

I'm working to prepare my master's degree admission.

So the admission team provided me with a declaration form and the first question is this:

> **Academic Disciplinary Action**
>
> Have you ever been placed on academic or non-academic suspension or dismissal from any educational
> institution?

I've got dismissed from the first college I've been to for absence problem and nothing else.

Does the absence goes under either academic or non-academic term ?

So should I choose Yes or No ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It asks if you've ever been dismissed from an educational institution, and you have. You should answer "yes". Dismissal due to absence would presumably count as "non-academic" dismissal, as you were not dismissed due to cheating or plagiarism, for example. If there is no place to explain it on the form, you could consider adding a line to your CV or personal statement to explain your reason for dismissal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the full answer.

Comment: OK, I have another point to ask about related to the same declaration form. Should I ask here ?

Comment: @R1S8K Separate questions should be posted separately. Thanks!

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer.

Comment: To me, "academic dismissal" would mainly refer to being dismissed for low grades, or otherwise not meeting academic standards.  Being absent would fall into that category, I would say.